# GeoJSON doesn't render on Map in OpenLayers project

Tags: geojson, openlayers

I seem to be stuck on a formatting issue of how OpenLayers reads the GeoJSON output I am presenting to it. In my webpage file, I have the following script:

```
<script type="module">
  var Feature = ol.Feature; //import Feature from 'ol/Feature.js';
  var Map = ol.Map; //import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
  var View = ol.View; //import View from 'ol/View.js';
  var Polyline = ol.format.Polyline; //import Polyline from 'ol/format/Polyline.js';
  var GeoJSON = ol.format.GeoJSON;
  var Point = ol.geom.Point; //import Point from 'ol/geom/Point.js';
  var {Tile, Vector} = ol.layer; //import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
  var TileLayer = Tile;
  var VectorLayer = Vector;

  //var BingMaps = ol.source.BingMaps; //import BingMaps from 'ol/source/BingMaps.js';

  var VectorSource = ol.source.Vector; //import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector.js';
  var {Circle, Fill, Icon, Stroke, Style} = ol.style; //import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Icon, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style.js';
  var CircleStyle = Circle;

var styleFunction = function (feature) {
  return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
};



var geojsonObject = {
  'type': 'FeatureCollection',
  'crs': {
    'type': 'name',
    'properties': {
      'name': 'EPSG:3857',
    },
  },
  'features': [
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [0, 0],
      },
    },
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'LineString',
        'coordinates': [
          [4e6, -2e6],
          [8e6, 2e6] ],
      },
    },
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'LineString',
        'coordinates': [
          [4e6, 2e6],
          [8e6, -2e6] ],
      },
    },
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': [
          [
            [-5e6, -1e6],
            [-4e6, 1e6],
            [-3e6, -1e6] ] ],
      },
    },
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'MultiLineString',
        'coordinates': [
          [
            [-1e6, -7.5e5],
            [-1e6, 7.5e5] ],
          [
            [1e6, -7.5e5],
            [1e6, 7.5e5] ],
          [
            [-7.5e5, -1e6],
            [7.5e5, -1e6] ],
          [
            [-7.5e5, 1e6],
            [7.5e5, 1e6] ] ],
      },
    },
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'MultiPolygon',
        'coordinates': [
          [
            [
              [-5e6, 6e6],
              [-5e6, 8e6],
              [-3e6, 8e6],
              [-3e6, 6e6] ] ],
          [
            [
              [-2e6, 6e6],
              [-2e6, 8e6],
              [0, 8e6],
              [0, 6e6] ] ],
          [
            [
              [1e6, 6e6],
              [1e6, 8e6],
              [3e6, 8e6],
              [3e6, 6e6] ] ] ],
      },
    },
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'GeometryCollection',
        'geometries': [
          {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': [
              [-5e6, -5e6],
              [0, -5e6] ],
          },
          {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [4e6, -5e6],
          },
          {
            'type': 'Polygon',
            'coordinates': [
              [
                [1e6, -6e6],
                [2e6, -4e6],
                [3e6, -6e6] ] ],
          } ],
      },
    } ],
};


var geojsonObject1 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    @foreach($parcels as $p)
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "{{$p->coordinates['type']}}",
        "coordinates": [[{{json_encode($p->coordinates['coordinates'][0][0])}}]]
      }
    }
    @if(!$loop->last), @endif
    @endforeach
   ]
};


var styles = {
  'LineString': new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'green',
      width: 1,
    }),
  }),
  'MultiLineString': new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'green',
      width: 1,
    }),
  }),
  'MultiPolygon': new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'yellow',
      width: 1,
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1)',
    }),
  }),
  'Polygon': new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'blue',
      lineDash: [4],
      width: 3,
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)',
    }),
  }),
  'GeometryCollection': new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'magenta',
      width: 2,
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'magenta',
    }),
    image: new CircleStyle({
      radius: 10,
      fill: null,
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: 'magenta',
      }),
    }),
  }),
  'Circle': new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'red',
      width: 2,
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
    }),
  }),
};

var styleFunction = function (feature) {
  return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
};

var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  features: new GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'}).readFeatures(geojsonObject),
});


var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: styleFunction,
});

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      vectorLayer,
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
      zoom: 4
    })
  });
    console.log(vectorSource);
  console.log(vectorLayer);
  map.render();
vectorSource.once('change',function(e){
  console.log(vectorSource);
  console.log(vectorLayer);
    if(vectorSource.getState() === 'ready') { 
        if(layers[0].getSource().getFeatures().length>0) {
            map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

The `geojsonObject` collection appears when called to render, but the `geojsonObject1` does not when I want to try and render it.

Here is a sample of my data from the `geojsonObject1` data:

```
var geojsonObject1 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
        {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [[[[-104.739810985448,40.5869690039517],[-104.740242592446,40.5869539996775],[-104.740253583381,40.5871377169226],[-104.739821976404,40.5871527203439],[-104.739810985448,40.5869690039517]]]]
      }
    }
    ,         {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [[[[-104.743405423672,40.589121663559],[-104.743628810286,40.5891205821628],[-104.743631498209,40.5894225042021],[-104.743408267704,40.5894235866252],[-104.743405423672,40.589121663559]]]]
      }
    }
    ,
```

Can anyone help me pinpoint where the breaking point might be where it doesn't want to read from my custom data of `geojsonObject1`?

Comment: Please start pinpointing yourself by making a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

In geojsonObject1 the coordinates are lon/lat while your view projection is the default web mercator so you will need to specify both projections when reading (otherwise the features will be on the equator 104 meters from the Greenwich meridian).  Also when you have already set the features in the vectorSource it will not change and you can fit the view immediately

```
var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject1, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'}),
});

var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: styleFunction,
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    vectorLayer,
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
    zoom: 4
  })
});

map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
```